# how to upload data to my dropbox from my android app?

Tags: android, file-upload, dropbox

I would like to write an app that could upload its app data continously to my dropbox(www.dropbox.com) if there is any changes. I search quite a number of methods but I don't really understand how to do. It is something similar to sync to cloud whatever. Is there a quick and easy to understand eclipse code to use? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dropbox sdk. Here the sample code:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android